# RegEx Etract the second URL from String

Tags: java

I'm trying to extract the second url from Stings like these

```
 submitted by <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/thecrappycoder"> thecrappycoder </a> <br /> <a href="http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2015/02/25/understanding-net-2015.aspx">[link]</a> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2x9o4o/understanding_net_2015/">[3 comments]</a>
 submitted by <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/durdn"> durdn </a> <br /> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG-UaBJXZ80">[link]</a> <a href="http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2x89le/hacking_with_andrew_and_brad_an_http2_client/">[1 comment]</a>
```

by using regex. I tried this.

```
String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&amp;@#/%=~_()|]";        
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);             
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);    
while(m.find()) {       
    String urlStr = m.group();  
    urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, 3);    
        links.add(urlStr);              
}
```

I also tried in that way

```
System.out.println(("http://"+text.split("http://")[1]).split("")[0]);
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it. Any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the same approach with a simplified regex pattern:

```
String text = "submitted by <a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/user/thecrappycoder\"> thecrappycoder </a> <br />" +
        " <a href=\"http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2015/02/25/understanding-net-2015.aspx\">[link]</a> " +
        "<a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2x9o4o/understanding_net_2015/\">[3 comments]</a>\n" +
        " ";
String regex = "href=.(http.*?)\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
m.find(); // ignore the 1st match
m.find(); // find the 2nd match
String urlStr = m.group(); // read the 2nd match
System.out.println("urlStr = " + urlStr); // prints: urlStr = http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2015/02/25/understanding-net-2015.aspx
```

Comment: Thank you alfasin for your elegant solution. I didn't know I can ignore the 1st match by doing that. Thank you!